# Can I tweak an app's storage permission and allow it to write on the phone but deny read?

Tags: storage, permissions, downloading

The example I'll use is with an internet browser app — let's say Opera. If I allow its storage permission, I can download files on my phone (write) but the app can read its storage as well (I verified this by hitting `file:///storage/emulated/0/` in the pathbar and I could freely browse all files on my phone).

If I deny its storage permission, it can no longer access `0/` but it also cannot download files.

If the download directory is pre-determined by the user, can we force it to only write and not read, thus being able to download files, without risking leaking data from our files to the app? I'm guessing maybe through ADB or something?

Comment: No. `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` always implies `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`. You can possibly devise some trick if your device is rooted. Note that an app's private directories in shared storage are always accessible to the app. Or they can ask the user to choose a directory (using SAF) whenever a file is to be downloaded. Privacy-friendly apps don't force the user to grant Storage permission in order to allow downloading a file.

Comment: I mean, I've tried with Opera, Firefox and Brave and all three request storage permission, in order to download a file. Question: Just to cross-reference, I went to my desktop and saw that yes there's all the other permissions — Location, Camera, Microphone, etc. — but not Storage as well. Why would it only be on mobile and not desktop as well? :/

Comment: Because your desktop might not be running Android. Every OS has it's own permission set to control access to resources.

Comment: Well, at the time of my reply, I had just checked my Mac OS desktop, but I just checked on my friend's Windows 10 laptop and it's also not supporting the option to disable storage access. I wonder if it's the same on Linux.

Comment: I think I failed to make my point in earlier comment. [Storage permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/#permissions) (`READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`) are specific to Android. How would you find those on Mac, Windows or Linux. It's something specific to an Operating System, not a software.

Comment: Oh ok, now I see. So, I'm suspecting my only solution is to keep the storage permission disabled on my browser app, and find an open source file downloader app (with its equivalent storage permission enabled), for whenever I need to download files from the internet? *Well, open source, or just an app that one deems as trustworthy enough to not leak data, anyway.*